# 2D sprite sorting and draw order relative to camera rotation

Tags: 2d, vector

I'm having trouble working out how to recalculate 2D sprite sorting / draw order based on camera rotation.

In the example below:

**Screen 1** shows a non-rotated typical "top down 2D" scene, where the grey objects can be sorted based on their screen Y position, drawn from top to bottom, so in this case B, A, C.

**Screen 2** shows the situation after the player/camera rotates clockwise, with the original screen up vector (green) and the new up vector (red). In this situation, sorting by object Y position will not work, because A should now be drawn after C.

What I need to do is to sort the objects not only by their Y position, but also relative to the new up vector and/or camera rotation, but I'm unsure how to handle this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was probably overthinking this quite a lot. The solution in the end was to just calculate the rotated position of the object by rotating their current position Vec2 by the inverse of the camera rotation. I could then sort by this rotated Y value.

Comment: If your question is solved, it would be helpful to mark this answer as the correct one, so the question won't bump in the homepage expecting more answers.

Comment: I'm aware, however it won't allow marking it as the answer until tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds good! Glad your problem was resolved :)